# Mass hung from the middle of a wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators

I am doing the exercises of "Vibration and Waves", French; and I got stuck in the point 3-7. This is the exercise:

> A wire of unstretched length $l_0$ is extended by a distance $10^{-3}l_0$ when a certain mass is hung from its bottom end. If the same wire is connected between two points, A and B, that are a distance $l_0$ apart on the same horizontal level, and the same mass is hung from the midpoint of the wire, what is the depression $y$ of the midpoint, and what is the tension of the wire?

[image: This is the image problem]

I was trying and I got that $K=10^3  \dfrac{mg}{l_0}$ (constant of the wire). I don't know how to analize the problem if the mass is on the midpoint. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You need to show an attempt to work through the problem. You can find tension $T$ in the wire in terms of $y$ by balancing forces on the hanging weight. From geometry you can find the extension $x$ in terms of $y$, which can also be used to relate $T=kx$.